# In PostgreSQL how can I return the entire row that corresponds with the min of a value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, min, amazon-redshift

So if I have a table like this

```
id | value | detail
-------------------
12 | 20    | orange
12 | 30    | orange
13 | 16    | purple
14 | 50    | red
12 | 60    | blue
```

How can I get it to return this?

```
12 | 20 | orange
13 | 16 | purple
14 | 50 | red
```

If I group by id and detail it returns both 12 | 20 | orange and 12 | 60    | blue

Comment: google "windowing functions postgresql"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9a275/6)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST( id INT, value INT, detail VARCHAR );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( 12, 20, 'orange' );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( 12, 30, 'orange' );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( 13, 16, 'purple' );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( 14, 50, 'red' );
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( 12, 60, 'blue' );
```

**Query 1**:

Not sure if Redshift supports this syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       FIRST_VALUE( id ) OVER wnd AS id,
       FIRST_VALUE( value ) OVER wnd AS value,
       FIRST_VALUE( detail ) OVER wnd AS detail
FROM   TEST
WINDOW wnd AS ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9a275/6/0)**:

```
| id | value | detail |
|----|-------|--------|
| 12 |    20 | orange |
| 14 |    50 |    red |
| 13 |    16 | purple |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT t.ID,
       t.VALUE,
       t.DETAIL
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY VALUE ) AS RN
  FROM   TEST
) t
WHERE  t.RN = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9a275/6/1)**:

```
| id | value | detail |
|----|-------|--------|
| 12 |    20 | orange |
| 13 |    16 | purple |
| 14 |    50 |    red |
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy task for a Windowed Aggregate Function, ROW_NUMBER:

```
select *
from
 (
   select t.*,
      row_number() 
      over (partition by id        -- for each id
            order by value) as rn  -- row with the minimum value
   from t
 ) as dt
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has a `DISTINCT ON` clause to address this case. With `DISTINCT ON (id)`, a query will return only the first record for each value of `id`. You control which record is selected via the `ORDER BY` clause. In your case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) *
FROM t
ORDER BY id, value
```

Comment: It says DISTINCT ON is not supported. It looks like redshift doesn't support it.

Comment: @Checco: Sorry, missed the Redshift tag. dnoeth's answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by value
limit 1;
```

If you have an index on `value`, an alternative method that returns all matching rows is:

```
select t.*
from table t
where value = (select min(value) from table t);
```

Then add a `limit` if you only want one row.

Comment: The first query will also use an index on `value`. The second would need to use it twice.